# How to repair GRUB from backup?

Tags: grub2, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 in dualboot. But the problem was that Windows didn't boot when GRUB is set as primary bootloader in BIOS. When the Windows EFI partition was checked as primary, Windows booted well.

Then I decided to fix it and installed Boot-Repair. First of all, I made the backup. Then updated the GRUB. The update was successful. But then Windows and Ubuntu didn't boot at all.

I've repaired GRUB using live-USB. Now I can boot Ubuntu, but Windows doesn't boot.

How can I restore boot partitions from Boot-Repair backup (.zip file)?

Comment: I have never seen anyone have to do a restore. Boot-Repair almost always fixes the issues if correct options are chosen. Did you install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM mode and Windows is in UEFI mode. If Boot-Repair thought you had buggy UEFI it may have renamed Windows efi boot file.   To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair. then you should be able to boot Windows. But you may need Ubuntu to be in UEFI boot mode to easily dual boot. Otherwise you have to use UEFI menu to choose system to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try [disabling Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) If it's enabled, some versions of GRUB can't boot Windows. This is a GRUB bug.

If that doesn't help, try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can try the USB flash drive or CD-R image without installing it, if you like; or dive in all the way by installing the Debian-package version in Ubuntu. (Note that the USB flash drive/CD-R version will boot Ubuntu correctly only if you do *not* have a separate `/boot` partition or if you manually edit your kernel options.) rEFInd is less finicky about booting Windows than is GRUB, so it's more likely to work if GRUB gives you problems.

If you prefer to stick to GRUB, that may be possible, but you'll need to provide more details about what's not working, like any error messages you're getting, whether you see a Windows logo appear, etc.

Sometimes this problem can be caused by a missing Windows boot loader. (Typically you'll get some variety of "file not found" message, or rEFInd won't show a Windows option at all, if this is the case.) You'll need to either restore the Windows boot loader files from a backup or use a Windows emergency disc to re-install the files to fix this problem.